# google chrome extension save files on client side

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webkit

So basically what is going on is:
1) Button click
2) External request which returns a json arrya
3) Loop through the array and save each element in a file (client side)

The problem is that the `console.log(fileName)` prints only the last element. So I'm getting `n` times the last filename.

Is there a way to trick `window.webkitRequestFileSystem` into doing what I need or maybe there is a workaround.

```
document.getElementById("reload-files").onclick = function() {
    reloadFiles(localStorage["user_mail"]);
}

function reloadFiles (email) {
  var files = [];
  var xhr    = new XMLHttpRequest();

  var url = "...url...&email="+escape(email);
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

      for (var i = resp.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        fileName = resp[i].name;
        fileData  = resp[i].data;
        files.push(fileName);
        // save file
        window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, resp[i].data.length, writeToFileStorage, errorHandler);
      };
      localStorage["files"] = JSON.stringify(files);
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}

function writeToFileStorage(fs) {
  fs.root.getFile(fileName, {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {

    // Create a FileWriter object for our FileEntry (log.txt).
    fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {

      fileWriter.onwriteend = function(e) {
        console.log(fileName);
      };

      var blob = new Blob([fileData], {type: 'application/javascript'});

      fileWriter.write(blob);

    }, errorHandler);

  }, errorHandler);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to store on the file system that you cant store in `localStorage`/`chrome.storage`

Comment: I could use localstorage but the data might exceed 5 mb, so I have to create files.

Comment: Nevermind this was incorrect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that `webkitRequestFileSystem` doesn't call its callback function immediately. Instead, it fires at a later time, after the current code is finished executing. Therefore, you generate a backlog of `writeToFileStorage` executions, all of which read the final `fileName` value, left after the `for` loop completes.

You can solve this by using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), which will generate new copies of your callback function with fixed arguments:

```
window.webkitRequestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT,
                               resp[i].data.length,
                               writeToFileStorage.bind(window, fileName, fileData),
                               errorHandler);
```

Then prepend those formal arguments to your callback definition, and make `fs` the final argument:

```
function writeToFileStorage(fileName, fileData, fs) {
    ...
}
```

That said, I question the efficiency of repeatedly requesting file system access. You could sum all of the `data.length` amounts, and make one single call to `webkitRequestFileSystem`. You could more the `for` loop inside the callback and invoke the callback exactly once.

Comment: thanks for the `bind`. and about the efficiency, the data has to be in different files, or did I get something wrong here ?
If I merge them together and call `webkitRequestFileSystem` only once, will that create only one file ? and how would I get the data in `file1`. The way I imagine this is that all the files will be merged into one string and then that will be written into the file.

Comment: @waaadim `webkitRequestFileSystem` requests file system space. `fs.root.getFile` actually creates files to fill that space. You're asking for a little bit of space, then filling it, and then asking for a little more space, then filling it, etc. I'm just suggesting you request all your space at once and then fill in all of your files (with repeated calls to `fs.root.getFile`) inside your callback.

Comment: ok, I'll change that. And about the `bind`, `fs` is undefinded in the function `writeToFileStorage`. It looks like `bind` is messing something up.

Comment: @waaadim Oh, sorry, I was missing the first argument to `bind`, which sets the function's `this` value. Edited.